# VacantEntry does not implement any method in scope named set

Tags: hashmap, rust

This snippet of code:

```
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry::{Occupied, Vacant};
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut vars = HashMap::<i32, f64>::new();
    let key = 10;
    let val = match vars.entry(key) {
        Vacant(entry) => entry.set(0.0),
        Occupied(entry) => entry.into_mut(),
    };

    *val += 3.4;
    println!("{}", val);
}
```

Gives this error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `set` found for type `std::collections::hash_map::VacantEntry<'_, i32, f64>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:8:32
  |
8 |         Vacant(entry) => entry.set(0.0),
  |                                ^^^
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`VacantEntry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.VacantEntry.html) doesn't implement any method named `set`, but there is a method named [`insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.VacantEntry.html#method.insert):

```
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry::{Occupied, Vacant};
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut vars = HashMap::<i32, f64>::new();
    let key = 10;
    // vars.insert(key, 25.0);
    let val = match vars.entry(key) {
        Vacant(entry) => entry.insert(0.0),
        Occupied(entry) => entry.into_mut(),
    };

    *val += 3.4;
    println!("{}", val);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=e4293371e8ab1eadcb7caa7912878971))

Comment: thanks. https://github.com/eliovir/rust-examples/blob/master/api-collections-hashmap.rs give me wrong example :(

Comment: @GigihAjiIbrahim Rust is changing rapidly in the runup to 1.0. Your best bet is to refer to the [official documentation site](http://doc.rust-lang.org/). Most (if not all) of the code examples there are compiled and tested against the current state of the language, so it's a good bet they will be correct.