# Implementing only IndexMut without implementing Index

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a `DefaultHashMap` struct which is basically a wrapper around `HashMap`, with the difference that when getting a key that is not in the map the default value is put in that key and is returned.

I made a `get` and a `get_mut` method and this works fine. Now I'm trying to implement `Index` and `IndexMut` as wrappers around those methods. Here I'm running into two problems.

The first problem is caused by the fact that `get` has to mutate the struct when the key is not present it requires a mutable reference. However, the signature for the `index` method of `Index` has `&self` instead of `&mut self`, so I cannot implement it.

This causes a second problem, `IndexMut` requires an `Index` implementation. So even though `IndexMut` would have no problems being implemented I cannot do this because `Index` cannot be implemented.

The first problem is annoying but understandable. For the second one, I don't get why the requirement is even there. I would like to have a way to work around it. Right now I'm doing the following, but I hope someone has a better solution:

```
impl<K: Eq + Hash, V: Clone> Index<K> for DefaultHashMap<K, V> {
    type Output = V;

    fn index(&self, _: K) -> &V {
        panic!("DefautHashMap doesn't implement indexing without mutating")
    }
}

impl<K: Eq + Hash, V: Clone> IndexMut<K> for DefaultHashMap<K, V> {
    #[inline]
    fn index_mut(&mut self, index: K) -> &mut V {
        self.get_mut(index)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you wrap a `RefCell<HashMap>` instead of just a `HashMap`?

Comment: @PeterHall Sadly, no. The `index()` method would need to return a `Ref<V>` instead of `&V` in order for this to work. I'd say the only sane way to do what JelteF wants is to write a standard method `get()` and either use `RefCell` or `&mut self`.

Comment: See also [Default mutable value from HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31141363/155423); [How to write a safe wrap for HashMap with default value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36141804/155423); [How does one create a HashMap with a default value in Rust?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41417660/155423); and [How to lookup from and insert into a HashMap efficiently?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28512394/155423).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I suspect that your requirement "*when getting a key that is not in the map the default value is put in that key*" is not exactly required!

Consider an immutable access `let foo = default_hash_map[bar] + 123;`. Unless you're going to use values with interior mutability with the map it might be inconsequential whether `default_hash_map[bar]` is actually creating a key or **just returns a reference to a single default value**.

Now, if you really need to create new entries during access then there is a way to do this. The borrow checker restriction that only allows you to add new entries with a mutable access is here to stop you from creating the dangling pointers that would occur whenever you modify the map while holding the references in there. But if you were using a structure with stable references, where stable means that the references are not invalidated when you enter new entries into the structure, then the problem the borrow checker is trying to prevent will go away.

In C++ I would've considered using a [deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) which is guaranteed by the standard not to invalidate its references when you add new entries to it. Unfortunately, Rust deques are different (though you can probably find *arena allocator* crates with properties similar to the C++ deque) and so for this example I'm using `Box`. The boxed values reside separately on the heap and aren't moved when you add new entries into `HashMap`.

Now, your normal access pattern is probably going to be *modifying* the new entries and then accessing the *existing* entries of the map. Thus making new entries in `Index::index` is an exception and shouldn't slow down the rest of the map. It might make sense therefore to pay the boxing price only for the `Index::index` access. To do that we might use a second structure, that keeps just the boxed `Index::index` values.

Knowing that `HashMap<K, Box<V>>` can be inserted into without invalidating the existing `V` refereces allows us to use it as a temporary buffer, holding the `Index::index`-created values until we get a chance to synchronize them with the primary `HashMap`.

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::ops::Index;
use std::ops::IndexMut;

struct DefaultHashMap<K, V>(HashMap<K, V>, UnsafeCell<HashMap<K, Box<V>>>, V);

impl<K, V> DefaultHashMap<K, V>
    where K: Eq + Hash
{
    fn sync(&mut self) {
        let buf_map = unsafe { &mut *self.1.get() };
        for (k, v) in buf_map.drain() {
            self.0.insert(k, *v);
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, K, V, Q: ?Sized> Index<&'a Q> for DefaultHashMap<K, V>
    where K: Eq + Hash + Clone,
          K: Borrow<Q>,
          K: From<&'a Q>,
          Q: Eq + Hash,
          V: Clone
{
    type Output = V;

    fn index(&self, key: &'a Q) -> &V {
        if let Some(v) = self.0.get(key) {
            v
        } else {
            let buf_map: &mut HashMap<K, Box<V>> = unsafe { &mut *self.1.get() };
            if !buf_map.contains_key(key) {
                buf_map.insert(K::from(key), Box::new(self.2.clone()));
            }
            &*buf_map.get(key).unwrap()
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, K, V, Q: ?Sized> IndexMut<&'a Q> for DefaultHashMap<K, V>
    where K: Eq + Hash + Clone,
          K: Borrow<Q>,
          K: From<&'a Q>,
          Q: Eq + Hash,
          V: Clone
{
    fn index_mut(&mut self, key: &'a Q) -> &mut V {
        self.sync();
        if self.0.contains_key(key) {
            self.0.get_mut(key).unwrap()
        } else {
            self.0.insert(K::from(key), self.2.clone());
            self.0.get_mut(key).unwrap()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    {
        let mut dhm = DefaultHashMap::<String, String>(HashMap::new(),
                                                       UnsafeCell::new(HashMap::new()),
                                                       "bar".into());
        for i in 0..10000 {
            dhm[&format!("{}", i % 1000)[..]].push('x')
        }
        println!("{:?}", dhm.0);
    }

    {
        let mut dhm = DefaultHashMap::<String, String>(HashMap::new(),
                                                       UnsafeCell::new(HashMap::new()),
                                                       "bar".into());
        for i in 0..10000 {
            let key = format!("{}", i % 1000);
            assert!(dhm[&key].len() >= 3);
            dhm[&key[..]].push('x');
        }
        println!("{:?}", dhm.0);
    }

    {
        #[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Clone, Copy, Hash, Debug)]
        struct K(u32);
        impl<'a> From<&'a u32> for K {
            fn from(v: &u32) -> K {
                K(*v)
            }
        }
        impl<'a> Borrow<u32> for K {
            fn borrow(&self) -> &u32 {
                &self.0
            }
        }
        let mut dhm = DefaultHashMap::<K, K>(HashMap::new(),
                                             UnsafeCell::new(HashMap::new()),
                                             K::from(&123));
        for i in 0..10000 {
            let key = i % 1000;
            assert!(dhm[&key].0 >= 123);
            dhm[&key].0 += 1;
        }
        println!("{:?}", dhm.0);
    }
}
```

([playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=aba79959e59fdc75923d01173fe25fb8&version=nightly))

Note that boxing only stabilizes the insertion of new entries. To *remove* the boxed entries you still need the mutable (`&mut self`) access to `DefaultHashMap`.

Comment: Thanks for the great and indepth answer! After trying to get RefCell working for a couple of hours I realised your part about reference invalidation. I then opted for your first solution to just not insert them into the map and document this. Because after thinking about the consequenses of this it normally does not indeed and if you really want to insert on access you could still use the `get_mut` method directly. The final crate can be found here in case you're interested: https://github.com/JelteF/defaultmap